# Move an image with Javascript using mouse events

Tags: javascript, html, events, mouseevent

This should be simple enough, but every time I try I end up with a different issue.

I am trying to move an image around the screen using mouse events such as mousedown, mouseup, mousemove, clientX and clientY.  I am then trying to apply it to the image using absolute positioning.

I thought the below code would work as I get the coordinates on the initial click, and then the idea was to update them with mouse movement, but this does not work.

```
var image;
var dog = document.getElementById("dogPic");
var cat = document.getElementById("catPic");

dog.addEventListener("mousedown", initialClick, false);
cat.addEventListener("mousedown", initialClick, false);




function initialClick(e) {
    var initialX = e.clientX;
    var initialY = e.clientY;
    image = document.getElementById(this.id);

    document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){

        var newX = e.clientX - initialX;
        var newY = e.clientY - initialY;  


        image.style.left = newX;
        image.style.top = newY;
    }, false);

}
```

I am not asking for a complete answer, but can anyone direct me as to how I can approach dragging an image around the screen using the mouse movement events?

Thanks

Comment: do #dogPic and #catPic have style `position: absolute;`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```js
var dog = document.getElementById("dogPic");
var cat = document.getElementById("catPic");
var moving = false;

dog.addEventListener("mousedown", initialClick, false);
cat.addEventListener("mousedown", initialClick, false);


function move(e){

  var newX = e.clientX - 10;
  var newY = e.clientY - 10;

  image.style.left = newX + "px";
  image.style.top = newY + "px";

  
}

function initialClick(e) {

  if(moving){
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove", move);
    moving = !moving;
    return;
  }
  
  moving = !moving;
  image = this;

  document.addEventListener("mousemove", move, false);

}
```

```css
#dogPic, #catPic {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

#dogPic {
  background: blue;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="dogPic"></div>
<div id="catPic"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, Endless.   I knew it was simple but for whatever reason was going about it all wrong.  This is what I was trying to attempt.

Comment: Nitpick: `moving` shouldn't be a global var; it'd be nicer to store moving as a data-moving or something attribute on the element.

Answer (score 5):

I made a modification to have a more realistic dragging experience. This required adding an X and Y offset so instead of jumping when picked up, the object seems to just move as expected.

```js
let gMouseDownX = 0;
let gMouseDownY = 0;
let gMouseDownOffsetX = 0;
let gMouseDownOffsetY = 0;

function addListeners() {
    document.getElementById('cursorImage').addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
}

function mouseUp() {
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', divMove, true);
}

function mouseDown(e) {
    gMouseDownX = e.clientX;
    gMouseDownY = e.clientY;

    var div = document.getElementById('cursorImage');

    //The following block gets the X offset (the difference between where it starts and where it was clicked)
    let leftPart = "";
    if(!div.style.left)
        leftPart+="0px";    //In case this was not defined as 0px explicitly.
    else
        leftPart = div.style.left;
    let leftPos = leftPart.indexOf("px");
    let leftNumString = leftPart.slice(0, leftPos); // Get the X value of the object.
    gMouseDownOffsetX = gMouseDownX - parseInt(leftNumString,10);

    //The following block gets the Y offset (the difference between where it starts and where it was clicked)
    let topPart = "";
    if(!div.style.top)
        topPart+="0px";     //In case this was not defined as 0px explicitly.
    else
        topPart = div.style.top;
    let topPos = topPart.indexOf("px");
    let topNumString = topPart.slice(0, topPos);    // Get the Y value of the object.
    gMouseDownOffsetY = gMouseDownY - parseInt(topNumString,10);

    window.addEventListener('mousemove', divMove, true);
}

function divMove(e){
    var div = document.getElementById('cursorImage');
    div.style.position = 'absolute';
    let topAmount = e.clientY - gMouseDownOffsetY;
    div.style.top = topAmount + 'px';
    let leftAmount = e.clientX - gMouseDownOffsetX;
    div.style.left = leftAmount + 'px';
}

addListeners();
```

```html
<div style="height:500px;width:500;background-color:blue;">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" id="cursorImage" ondragstart="return false;"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This code work with just plain javascript

```js
function addListeners() {
    document.getElementById('image').addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
}

function mouseUp() {
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', divMove, true);
}

function mouseDown() {
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', divMove, true);
}

function divMove(e){
    var div = document.getElementById('image');
    div.style.position = 'absolute';
    div.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';
    div.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
}


addListeners();
```

```html
<div style="height:500px;width:500;background-color:blue;">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" id="image" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Super simple working code with Jquery. Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/djjL16p2/

```
<div id="content" style="margin-top: 100px">
    <img id="lolcat" src="http://obeythekitty.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/lolcat_airplane.jpg" style="height: 100px; width: 120px; position: absolute;" draggable="false" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#lolcat").mousedown(function() {
    $(this).data("dragging", true);
});

$("#lolcat").mouseup(function() {
    $(this).data("dragging", false);
});

$("#lolcat").mousemove(function(e) {
    if (!$(this).data("dragging"))
        return;
    $(this).css("left", e.clientX - $(this).width()/2);
    $(this).css("top", e.clientY - $(this).height()/2);
});
```

Comment: I would say it's wrong to assume he is using jQuery or should have to use it. this guy made everything with vanilla javascript and should be answered as such

Comment: @Endless: I certainly agree with you. My intent with the answer is to provide a working approach for OP. I'm certain he's capable of porting it to Vanilla JS, it'd just be a bit more verbose.

Comment: Sorry, I should state I cannot use jQuery for this.  Thanks for the answer though

Comment: There is no need to write all such code unless one does not want to use jqueryui. With the latter you just need only line of code: $('#lolcat').draggable();

Answer (score 0):

although this is an old question, it has been viewed many times and is high in google search results, so i thought i would provide an answer to this question

```js
dog.onpointerdown           = pd;
cat.onpointerdown           = pd;
document.onpointerup        = ()=>document.onpointermove=null;

function pd(e){  
  e.preventDefault();       //  <-- comment this line and drag the img 
  node                      = e.target;  
  mx                        = e.pageX;
  my                        = e.pageY;
  document.onpointermove    = pm;
}

function pm(e){
  dx                        = e.pageX-mx;
  dy                        = e.pageY-my;
  mx                        = e.pageX;
  my                        = e.pageY;
  x                         = parseInt(node.style.left)+dx;
  y                         = parseInt(node.style.top)+dy;
  node.style.left           = x+'px';
  node.style.top            = y+'px';
}
```

```css
#dog,#cat {
  position      : absolute;
  width         : 30px;
  height        : 30px;
  border        : 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id=dog style='top:50px;left:50px'></div>
<img id=cat style='top:50px;left:100px' src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAVtJREFUKFN10E0ow3EAxvHvb/+NaZMVzUt28FLiprycUA6SUqZGlANXNykXB8mJyEUIJ0UUeQsptMRBXg5m5W0kYYfhb9pf/9l+CgcHnvPn8DyPCIVCkr8iDOyuTmLxDGGrGkD8B8MR2OqtpsZxhVup+wWFQNeCPPvvMJmt2FIy2RlwUpl0wnK4FvGqqlIoRvw3pxg3W7FGn1FiTJwm1HF/7aUmcZ/rwnHEhfdEzo90Ygh4vpq2lwukDsGIgb0bhZw0E+b6VYR7Y1FuT/dTnBzkSY+jMdePjAgEcBmIoriWSEnPQszNTMrDlVHyMyz4vMc0laRij9VQRIT9ezNFXR40TUNo77o8XBgk72GYwMsbssWDea0BNfDIk+KgtGP9B2qavPDdok9V8GpIoqz7gLOJRs5VK3ZHNgXONj7C4e97oqY4tvpcyFgb1W1jHMz2cORTcTY0E2/P+Br5CcV6mGQ0mtQdAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC'>
```

**the above code has one caveat that led me to this question**

i was trying to move an image around using the mouse

in the `pd` function if `e.preventDefault()` is commented, the image can no longer be dragged although the div is fine, tested in desktop chrome and firefox

it seems the browser specifically prevents dragging images, a `pointercancel` event is even fired

can anyone shed any light on this behaviour