# How to drag and drop image on another image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to drag an image and drop it on another image. When I try to drop an image on the other the dragged image disappears. After dropping the image I want the image behind it to disappear(i.e. not the dragged image). But whenever I try to do this, the dragged image is disappearing. Any suggestions?

Here's the code which I tried code:

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function dragStart(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function dragDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

```css
.div1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid #2C74B3;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

p {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.gfg {
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #F08A5D;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.img {
  width: 250;
  height: 250;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.row1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 750px;
  height: 250px;
}

.d1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
  /*background-color: #2B2E4A;*/
}

.d2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 582px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
  /*background-color: #2B2E4A;*/
}

.d3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid #2C74B3;
  border-radius: 25px;
  /*background-color: #2B2E4A;*/
}

.d4 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 582px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid #2C74B3;
  border-radius: 25px;
  /*background-color: #2B2E4A;*/
}

.d5 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
  /*background-color: #2B2E4A;*/
}

.d6 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 582px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
  /*background-color: #2B2E4A;*/
}

.d7 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.d8 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid #2C74B3;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!--<div class="gfg">DRAG AND DROP</div>
    <p>Image Drag and Drop in boxes</p>-->
<br>
<br>
<div class="row1">
  <div class="d1">
  </div>

  <div class="div1 used-boxes" ondrop="dragDrop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

    <img id="drag1" class="img" src="C:\Users\Username\Documents\image.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)">
  </div>

  <div class="d2"></div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="row1">
  <div class="d3 used-boxes" ondrop="dragDrop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  </div>

  <div class="d7 used-boxes" ondrop="dragDrop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

    <img id="drag2" class="img" src="C:\Users\Username\Downloads\image.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)">
  </div>

  <div class="d4 used-boxes" ondrop="dragDrop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="row1">
  <div class="d5">
  </div>

  <div class="d8 used-boxes" ondrop="dragDrop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  </div>

  <div class="d6"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: i think you are confusing dragging items using the mouse and "drag and drop", "drag and drop" is used for dragging items into the browser, like files from the os, i once answered a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33948464/move-an-image-with-javascript-using-mouse-events/77017845#77017845